# Error while building Linux module of a wireless driver

Tags: debian, networking, kernel-modules, make

I have recently installed Debian Wheezy onto one of my old computers to test it out and to become more familiar with Unix. To my surprise I enjoy the interface very much so far, but I have run into a problem:

When I go to install my wireless driver I get an error when I type `make`. I have installed the `build-essential` and the `linux-headers` packages, but I still get the problem. My terminal looks like

```
root@debian:/Wireless-Driver/rtl8192u_linux_2.6.0006.1031.2008# make
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-686-pae'
CC [M]  /Wireless-Driver/rtl8192u_linux_2.6.0006.1031.2008/ieee80211/ieee80211_rx.o
In file included from /Wireless-river/rtl8192u_linux_2.6.0006.1031.2008/ieee80211/ieee80211_rx.c:46:0:
/Wireless-Driver/rtl8192u_linux_2.6.0006.1031.2008/ieee80211/ieee80211.h:2107:24: error: field ‘ps_task’ has incomplete type    
make[4]: *** [/Wireless-Driver/rtl8192u_linux_2.6.0006.1031.2008/ieee80211/ieee80211_rx.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [_module_/Wireless-Driver/rtl8192u_linux_2.6.0006.1031.2008/ieee80211] Error 2
make[2]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-686-pae'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Sorry in advance for the horrible style.
My wireless adapter is a D'link DWA 130C

Comment: A syntax error in the source probably means the sources are supposed to be compiled with a different compiler. Did `./configure` return any warnings about your environment?

Comment: Can you specify where you obtained the driver sources from?

Comment: There is no file `./configure`

Comment: I obtained the drivers from D'link's website. http://support.dlink.ca/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DWA-130

Comment: The driver you are building (rtl8192u) is officially supported by Debian actually: https://wiki.debian.org/rtl819x

Comment: @SkyDan their instructions say to add a repo but I have no internet connection to do so :(

Comment: You probably don't have the same kernel version as the driver authors. @SkyDan The Linux kernel is meant to be compiled with GCC. It could be a version of GCC that's too old, but that's rarely an issue nowadays. Usually the problem is with the kernel version: APIs inside the kernel are not stable.